# Parsing XML to an array for GMaps API using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm teaching myself javascript by creating my wedding website using the google maps API.  I've figured out a lot through the docs and copypasta experimentation, but don't know how to make this happen: what I want to do is read an external XML file containing icon information (names and offsets for a sprite image containing the icons), and store it in an array that I can access when creating map markers.  For example, I want to be able to create a marker for the reception and assign it the icon "party".  Here's the code I have so far for reading the icon file:

```
        jQuery.get("markericons.xml", {}, function(data) {
        jQuery(data).find("markericon").each(function() {
            var icon = jQuery(this);
            var name = icon.attr("name");
            var url = 'images/icons/mapsprites.png';
            var size = new google.maps.Size(32, 37);
            var origin = new google.maps.Point(parseInt(icon.attr("x")),parseInt(icon.attr("y")));
            var anchor = new google.maps.Point((origin.x+16),origin.y);
            var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(url, size, origin, anchor);
        });
    });  // how to store this in an array so that I can access elements by name later?
```

And then, when creating the actual placemarks on the google map, something like the following:

```
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: icon.name=="party",  // pseudo-code... how to do this?
                title: title
            });
```

I'm still a programming noob, so I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a JSON object outside of your `.each()` or `.get()` method, depending on how accessible you want it to be (i'm guessing outside of `.get()`, so we'll use that for this example) and then create a JSON object out of your variables inside your `.each()`.

```
var storage = {}
jQuery.get("markericons.xml", {}, function(data) {
    jQuery(data).find("markericon").each(function() {
        var icon = jQuery(this),
            name = icon.attr("name");
        storage[name] = {
            url: 'images/icons/mapsprites.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(parseInt(icon.attr("x")),parseInt(icon.attr("y"))),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point((origin.x+16),origin.y),
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(url, size, origin, anchor)
        };
    });
});
```

now, you can access your google maps stuff by name:

```
// for this purpose, let's say `name` is "reception":
console.log(storage.reception) 
// => prints out { url: ..., size: ..., origin: ..., anchor: ..., icon: ... }
```

also, in your original JS, you have `icon` declared twice, so I'm not too sure what you want to do with that.

Comment: I think I can make this work, thanks!  BTW I think that it gets declared twice because the first time, it holds the XML node that I use to obtain the attributes.  The second time I redefine it to hold a google.maps.MarkerImage object.  It wasn't clearly explained in the example I cribbed it from...

Comment: no problem.  just might want to consider changing the variable names and make them unique.  if you're not using the first `icon` more than once, you can also do this: `var name = jQueryr(this).attr('name');`

Answer (score 0):

You should use GIcon: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GIcon

example how to use it: 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/icon-simple.html

Comment: that's the old version of the GMaps API; google.maps.MarkerImage replaces GIcon.  Thanks though.